# Cascading DropDownList in .NET Core

Tags: sql, ajax, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am trying to use the tutorial linked below but adapting it to my SQL DB for States, Districts, Schools tables that I already have in place.  I am new to .NET Core MVC and do not understand the error nor how to debug it. Any help appreciated.

[Cascading DropDownList In .NET Core](https://www.findandsolve.com/articles/cascading-dropdownlist-in-net-core-5#:%7E:text=NET%20Core,-Selena%20Kandakar&text=A%20cascading%20drop%2Ddown%20list,the%20user%20from%20another%20DropDownList.)

Error:
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'State'.'
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
CascadingExample.Controllers.HomeController.Index() in HomeController.cs

```
        [External Code]

using CascadingExample.Entities;
using CascadingExample.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CascadingExample.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly MyDBContent _con;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, MyDBContent con)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _con = con;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.StateList = _con.State.ToList();
            return View();
        }
            

        public JsonResult GetDistrictByStateID(int statedID)
        {
            var data = _con.District.Where(x => x.StateID == statedID).ToList();
            return Json(data);
        }


        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            return View();
        }


        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72132750) a little while ago. You're supposed to edit the original question, not delete and repost it.

Comment: I was told I posted it incorrectly.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. When that happens, you should edit the question according to the guidance you've received, and the question will get reopened if it's on-topic. Deleting the original question and then reposting it affects your question-asking privileges. Please refrain from doing this in the future.

Comment: Ok I understand

Answer (score 0):

The error means the table named 'State' has not created or the Database you are referring has not created

I checked the dbcontext in your tutorial,and it will not create the table"State".

```
public class MyDBContent:DbContext
    {
        private IConfigurationRoot _config;
        public MyDBContent(IConfigurationRoot config, DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
            _config = config;
        }
        public DbSet<Category> Category { get; set; }
        public DbSet<SubCategory> SubCategory { get; set; }

 

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(_config["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]);//connection string get by appsetting.json
        }
    }
```

You need to add these codes:

```
public DbSet<State> State { get; set; }
```